# complexity of subset searching of dates in datetuples

Tags: date, complexity-theory, timespan

I have the following problem:

A rather big collection of date tuples and other data should be accessed with as low complexity as possible. e.g.:

(10-08-1992, 21-10-1996, "OBJECT DATA1"),
(14-02-2012, 12-03-2044, "OBJECT DATA2"),
(12-12-1994, 12-12-1995, "OBJECT DATA3"),
(01-01-1993, 05-11-1995, "OBJECT DATA4"), etc.

I would like to access this collection by a singular date like 02-02-1995, and  get back a collection of objects that encapsulate this date. In the example this would be object 1, 3 and 4.

What I tried is to make two collections. One sorted by the first date, and the other sorted by the second date. I then want to do a intersection algorithm to find what overlaps.

However, that still is O(n). The problem however sounds like it lends to a smaller complexity. Because now I might as well just iterate over the entire collection.

Am I missing something crucial?

Comment: I think your approach is O(n log n) since sorting takes this much time. And since you need to consider every tuple, there’s no way you could get under O(n). If similarly requests come regularly, you can presort your collection once and then handle each request in less than O(n), probably down to O(log n).

Comment: The collection is preset and immutable. The requests itself have to be as efficient as possible

Comment: An idea: Take out the tuples where both dates are the same. Sort them into an array of lists where the array spans the possible date range so that each inner list holds tuples with one date only. Now you can access the tuples for a single date in O(1).